# How to read USB mouse data using STM32f103C OTG USB functionality?

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32f103

I wanted to build a project where is a screen displaying a pointer, and I wanted this pointer location to be determined by a USB mouse, so I used the ARM 32bit based STM32f103C microcontroller which feature a USB OTG_FS, I usually use stm32duino core in the ArduinoIDE to program my board, I searched all examples and they were all about emulating a HID device with the STM32f103C but I want the reverse, I want to receive mouse data not to emulate a mouse then send data via USB,So i think this is probably possible but I searched the internet and couldn't find anything to help.

**Edit**:
So, to be following the curriculum of stack exchange site, my question is converted into which is the best software needed for the STM32 I have that contains USB examples and can be run in my 64 bit Linux computer.

So in a nutshell I want to receive USB data in my board the STM32f103c.

Comment: It is much to broad and I afraid you will need to use HAL and write the rest. It is very unlikely to get Arduino style code for the host device

Comment: "So in a nutshell, I wan't to receive USB data": no, that's simply not true; you want to have a USB mouse driver, and that's way easier than the general case of receiving USB data. I think you have a very superficial understanding of USB only, and it would be a good idea to deepen that. Arduino won't really help you with bringing up a USB host interface, so you'll be writing that yourself – or you could abandon Arduino as platform and use one of the RTOSes that actually come with USB host examples and maybe even HID drivers.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am 15 years old (still young) and I never changed my coding environment which is the Arduino IDE, but for sometime now I think I would change it  but I can't find any other Arduino compatible coding environment compatible with my Linux fedora operating system, so would you please tell me more about the RTOSes ???

Comment: @MarcusMüller also can any jetbrains program be used instead of Arduino IDE ?

Comment: I don't know. I don't know every possible IDE out there on the planet, I just know that the Arduino platform (i.e. the microcontroller part of this) isn't suitable for what you're planning.

Comment: I understand, so you suggest changing my coding platform to a platform that strongly supports my microcontroller right ?

Comment: An RTOS is a *real-time operating system*, ie. a piece of software that makes it possible for you to write programs for your microcontroller (like the arduino platform does) in a way that allows you to react to certain things in guaranteed time (very much unlike what Arduino offers). Usually, an RTOS comes with some kind of abstraction for "tasks" (like: when data comes in from USB, execute this part of my program) and some "hardware abstraction layer" (so that you don't need to learn how to deal with the details of your hardware). For your STM32, a lot of choices – mbed, ChibiOS, FreeRTOS…

Comment: so yes, you'd want to abandon anything related to Arduino and go for something that simply isn't Arduino, because Arduino really is architected in a way that makes dealing with certain hardware impossible – not just on your specific microcontroller, but in general.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - there's plenty of reasons not to use Arduino, but **there's no need to make false claims about it**.  In fact people *do* host USB mice in Arduino sketches, on boards with host capability in the hardware and supported by the Arduino port.  For example, on the Due: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/USBHost . The actual problem in *this* question of course is not software at all, but that the chosen hardware lacks the capability.  For the STM32F103 a PS/2 mouse could be a practical option.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately STM32F103 series do not have OTG_FS hardware. Reference manual is misleading as it mentions both OTG_FS and USB Device modules. This is because some parts in this family have it (like STM32F105). You can use STM32CubeMX to find a microcontroller by filtering them according to selected criteria.

A framework based on ArduinoIDE is probably not the best approach for developing a USB host application. I suggest starting with STM32Cube examples. I haven't tried it myself, but STM32CubeMX seems to be able to generate USB Host HID class code.